# Where to find Source code of libjingle_peerconnection_so.so file

Tags: android, webrtc, licode

I am using Licode Client Sample project which contains libjingle_peerconnection jar and libjingle_peerconnection_so.so which is used for webRTC.

My query is:
Is there any way to extract the code from the libjingle_peerconnection_so.so file.
If its possible please help me how can I attempt this.

Comment: why do you think that it is open source? And even if it is - why do you think that we are here to google for you?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the libjingle has ended up being a Google's library and it is now known as "WebRTC Native Code Package". It's a part of the Google Chrome browser.

Relevant pages:

https://webrtc.org/native-code/

https://webrtc.googlesource.com/src